# Show WooCommerce Notices for AJAX add to cart function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to change the add to cart behaviour for my WooCommerce shop to an AJAX functionality in order to save time and increase the UX. I found [this very helpful tutorial](https://quadlayers.com/woocommerce-ajax-add-to-cart/) which works like a charm.

However the WooCommerce notices donÄt show up with this solution. I'd like to see the success message "product added to cart - show cart" as well as notices regarding low stock level etc. How does the code need to be changed in order to display the notices add the place where the usually show up as well?

Thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    $thisbutton = $(this),
                $form = $thisbutton.closest('form.cart'),
                id = $thisbutton.val(),
                product_qty = $form.find('input[name=quantity]').val() || 1,
                product_id = $form.find('input[name=product_id]').val() || id,
                variation_id = $form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val() || 0;
    var data = {
            action: 'ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart',
            product_id: product_id,
            product_sku: '',
            quantity: product_qty,
            variation_id: variation_id,
        };
    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function (response) {
                $thisbutton.removeClass('added').addClass('loading');
            },
            complete: function (response) {
                $thisbutton.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');
            }, 
            success: function (response) { 
                if (response.error & response.product_url) {
                    window.location = response.product_url;
                    return;
                } else { 
                    $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart', [response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton]);
                } 
            }, 
        }); 
     }); 
});
```

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart'); 

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');          

function ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {  
    
    $product_id = apply_filters('ql_woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));
    $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($_POST['quantity']);
    $variation_id = absint($_POST['variation_id']);
    $passed_validation = apply_filters('ql_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);
    $product_status = get_post_status($product_id); 
    
    if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) { 
        
        do_action('ql_woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);
        
        if ('yes' === get_option('ql_woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')) { 
            wc_add_to_cart_message(array($product_id => $quantity), true); 
        } 
           
        WC_AJAX :: get_refreshed_fragments(); 
    } else { 
        $data = array( 
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters('ql_woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id));
                
        echo wp_send_json($data);
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Any update... i'm looking for the same functionnality..

Comment: Unfortunately not yet

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the user that there was an error I modified the code a bit. The user will now be redirected to the details page, in case there was an error.

For the success case, I didnt find a solution. But I hope it helps anyway.

I modified JSs: beforeSend, complete, success functions
and PHPs: passed_validation variable

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $thisbutton = $(this),
        $form = $thisbutton.closest('form.cart'),
        id = $thisbutton.val(),
        product_qty = $form.find('input[name=quantity]').val() || 1,
        product_id = $form.find('input[name=product_id]').val() || id,
        variation_id = $form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val() || 0;
    var data = {
        action: 'ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart',
        product_id: product_id,
        product_sku: '',
        quantity: product_qty,
        variation_id: variation_id,
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function (response) {
            $thisbutton.removeClass('added').addClass('loading');
        },
        complete: function (response) {
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.error && response.product_url) {
                window.location = response.product_url;
                return;
            } else {
                $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart', [response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton]);
                $thisbutton.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');
            }
        },
    });
});});
```

PHP Code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');

function ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {

    $product_id = apply_filters('ql_woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));
    $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($_POST['quantity']);
    $variation_id = absint($_POST['variation_id']);
    $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id);
    $product_status = get_post_status($product_id);

    if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) {

        do_action('ql_woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);

        if ('yes' === get_option('ql_woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message(array($product_id => $quantity), true);
        }

        WC_AJAX :: get_refreshed_fragments();
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters('ql_woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id));

        echo wp_send_json($data);
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using same functionality as you guys and I think I made it to work as expected. Obviously I cannot guarantee that this approach is the best one. Inside main function I have added two things based on my functionality (added product variable and also called `wc_notices()` function):

```
$product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));
$quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($_POST['quantity']);
$variation_id = absint($_POST['variation_id']);
$passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);
$product_status = get_post_status($product_id);

// ASSIGNED PRODUCT VARIABLE
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) {
    
    do_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);

    if ('yes' === get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')) {
        wc_add_to_cart_message(array($product_id => $quantity), true);
    }
    
    // CALLED NOTICE FUNCTION + PRODUCT TITLE
    $message = $product->get_title() . ' - successfully added to the cart!';
    wc_add_notice( $message, 'success' ); 
    WC_AJAX :: get_refreshed_fragments();
} else {
    $data = array(
        'error' => true,
        'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id));

    echo wp_send_json($data);
}

wp_die();
```

And later on I have added additional filter for `$fragments`.

```
function update_notices_ajax_add_to_cart_add_fragments($fragments) {
    $all_notices  = WC()->session->get( 'wc_notices', array() );
    $notice_types = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_notice_types', array( 'error', 'success', 'notice' ) );

    ob_start();

    foreach ($notice_types as $notice_type) {
        if (wc_notice_count( $notice_type ) > 0) {
            wc_get_template("notices/{$notice_type}.php", array(
                'notices' => array_filter( $all_notices[ $notice_type ] ),
            ));
        }
    }
    $fragments['notices_html'] = ob_get_clean();

    wc_clear_notices();

    return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'update_notices_ajax_add_to_cart_add_fragments' );
```

So when you add new product to the cart, ajax function that we use returns response with latest woo fragments information. And on success ajax call I am passing it to append to `woocommerce-notices-wrapper` like this

```
$('.woocommerce-notices-wrapper').append(response.fragments.notices_html);
```

I hope it helps.